# Function in gcc source code

Tags: gcc

Can any one tell me which function in gcc source code is responsible for finding a macro in C file and repalce it  with actual value ?

I want to know the function as I have  to take  log by making  changes to it, so that at the end my log file will contain  where all macro is used and its line number .

Answer (score 0):

It's done by the preprocessor, prior to generating the output file.  If you want to see what it is doing, try gcc -E

From man gcc:

```
-E  Stop after the preprocessing stage; do not run the compiler proper.
    The output is in the form of preprocessed source code, which is sent to
    the standard output.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply .But I wanted exact funtion in gcc source which finds and replaces the macro .

Comment: Current GCC has the preprocessor embedded in the compiler, it is not a separate program anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `clang` for this type of task. It is pretty well documented and you don't need to change its source, as it's extendable with a plugin system.

In your case you create a plugin based on the `PPCallbacks` class and override its `MacroExpanded` method, and any other method you find useful. [This](https://github.com/chisophugis/clang_plugin_example/blob/master/FindDependencies.cpp) is an easy starting point.